# 2 dynamically created select box using jquery

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

I just want to create a 2 select box where if a user select an option in first select box, second select box also select that option value or let's say the 2 select box must select 1 identical index value

Select Box 1 selects index value 2, then select box 2 also selects index value 2 onChange and vice versa

Here's my code but only the 2 select boxes in the first row is good, if I create a new row, no effect

The jQuery:

```
$("#fCVCode\\[\\]").change(function() {
  var code = $(this).attr('value');
  $(this).parent().parent().find("#fCVDesc\\[\\]").val(code);

});
$("#fCVDesc\\[\\]").change(function() {
  var code = $(this).attr('value');
  $(this).parent().parent().find("#fCVCode\\[\\]").val(code);

});
```

the form

```
<td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
     <select style="text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%;" name="fCVCode[]" id="fCVCode[]">';
      $s = rand(1,99);
      for( $i = 0; $i <= $s; $i++ ) {
       $display .= '<option value="'.$i.'">Code '.rand(1,300).'</option>';
      }
     $display .= '</select>
     </td>
     <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
     <select style="text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%;" name="fCVDesc[]" id="fCVDesc[]">';
      for( $i = 0; $i <= $s; $i++ ) {
       $display .= '<option value="'.$i.'">Desc '.rand(1,300).'</option>';
      }
     $display .= '</select>
     </td>
```

Hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes have to be unique, so first use only the name (and remove those invalid duplicate IDs), then use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this:

```
$("#tableId").delegate("select[name='fCVCode[]']", "change", function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find("select[name=fCVDesc[]").val(code);
}).delegate("select[name='fCVDesc[]']", "change", function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find("select[name=fCVCode[]").val(code);
});
```

When you do a selector like `$("#fCVDesc\\[\\]")` it finds the elements matching that selector (well, the *first* matching it since it's an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)) and binds to *those*, not any created in the future...[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) would listen for bubbling events on the `<table>` working for new rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to modify the code you've answered to my current table structure

This works but have no idea how to minimize it

```
$("#fCVCode\\[\\]").change(function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().parent().find("select").val(code);
});
$("#fCVDesc\\[\\]").change(function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().parent().find("select").val(code);
});

$("#fCode\\[\\]").change(function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().parent().find("select").val(code);
});
$("#fDesc\\[\\]").change(function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().parent().find("select").val(code);
});
```

my current table structure goes something like this

```
<table id="fAddCVDetails">
<tr>
<th>Headers</th>
</tr>
<tr class="clone">
<td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
     <select style="text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%;" name="fCVCode[]" id="fCVCode[]">';
      $s = rand(1,99);
      for( $i = 0; $i <= $s; $i++ ) {
       $display .= '<option value="'.$i.'">Code '.rand(1,300).'</option>';
      }
     $display .= '</select>
     </td>
     <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
     <select style="text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%;" name="fCVDesc[]" id="fCVDesc[]">';
      for( $i = 0; $i <= $s; $i++ ) {
       $display .= '<option value="'.$i.'">Desc '.rand(1,300).'</option>';
      }
     $display .= '</select>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

another question is, does this code really finds the select element with that given name attribute?

```
find("select[name='fCVCode\\[\\]']");
```

coz I tried this code to get a value from the textarea to other input text type element and didn't work for me

```
$("i m g[name=fCVNoteInsert\\[\\]]").click(function() {
 $(this).parent().parent().find("div").fadeOut(200);
 value = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("textarea").val();
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("INPUT[name='fCVLeadTime\\[\\]']").val(value);
});
```

and the form is (Note: the table structure below has 5 inputs, so if I put find("input") all inputs will have the same values. And if I put find("#fCVLeadTime") only the first row input with id fCVLeadTime changes it's value this problem is just the same as my first posted problem.)

```
<table id="fAddCVDetails"> <tr> <th>Headers</th> </tr> <tr> <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;"><span><input type="text" id="fCVLeadTime[]" name="fCVLeadTime[]" style="width: 99%;" value="" /></span></td>
     <div id="noteAttach[]" name="noteAttach[]" class="attachment b-all ds">
      <i m g s rc="imageicon" border="0" id="fCVNoteInsert[]" name="fCVNoteInsert[]" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Insert Note">
      <span style="float: right;">
       <i m g s rc="imageicon" border="0" id="fCVNoteClose[]" name="fCVNoteClose[]" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Close Window">
      </span>
      <div style="padding: 5px;"></div>
      <textarea type="file" id="note[]" name="note[]" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
     </div>
      <i m g s rc="imageicon" border="0" name="fCVNotes[]" style="cursor: pointer;" title="'.PR_FORM_DOC_TTIP_UPLOAD_NOTE.'">
     </td> </tr> </table>
```

sorry I can't post images so I add spaces in between letters of image and source tags